# Proceso de backups desconocido - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Hola amigos he revisado el log del sql server y también el historial de backups y observo que se están realizando backups en disco a una determinada hora pero veo ningún plan de mantenimiento o algún JOB que realice esto, donde mas puede buscar el proceso?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Busca en el sistema operativo en donde esté implementado SQL Server, ya que alguien pudo haber usado Windows Task Scheduler para programar esto mediante un script T-SQL ejecutado mediante SQLCMD. Dicha persona debe tener privilegios tanto de Local Admin en el sistema operativo como de SYSADMIN en SQL Server para realizar dicha actividad.

En la base de soporte de Microsoft, indican como se puede hacer esto, sin necesidad de un Job o Plan de Mantenimiento en SQL Server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas de hacer un respaldo sin que sea un plan de mantenimiento, como indica @Guillermo, 
Esta consulata te permite ver donde se guardan y que usuario se utilizo para hacer el respaldo [Autor del script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/10/sql-server-get-database-backup-history-for-a-single-database/)

```
-- Get Backup History for required database
SELECT TOP 100
    s.database_name,
    s.description,
    m.physical_device_name,
    CAST(CAST(s.backup_size / 1000000 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14)) + ' ' + 'MB' AS bkSize,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, s.backup_start_date,
    s.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + 'Seconds' TimeTaken,
    s.backup_start_date,
    CAST(s.first_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)) AS first_lsn,
    CAST(s.last_lsn AS VARCHAR(50)) AS last_lsn,
    CASE s.[type] 
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
        WHEN 'I' THEN 'Differential'
        WHEN 'L' THEN 'Transaction Log'
    END AS BackupType,
    s.server_name,
    s.recovery_model,
    s.user_name
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
WHERE s.database_name = DB_NAME() -- Eliminar es ta linea para ver todas las BD
ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC, backup_finish_date
```